# Chrome Remote Debugging - Getting Page Notifications

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools, remote-debugging

I'm remote debugging Chrome, using the `--remote-debugging-port` switch and running another Chrome instance from which I'm debugging using web sockets. That's a bit different from most examples I see online where the debugging is done using node.js.

I need to navigate to a page, then evaluating some code in it. Both these actions work as expected using this code, that I run in a page in the 2nd Chrome instance:

```
var socket = new WebSocket(url);
function debug(action, data){
    var msg;
    switch (action) {
        case 'NAVIGATE':
            msg = {'id':1001, 'method':'Page.navigate', 'params':{'url':data.urlToNavigate}};
            break;
        case 'EVALUATE':
            msg = {'id':1002, 'method':'Runtime.evaluate', 'params':{'expression':data.jsCodeToEvaluate}};
            break;
    }
    socket.send(JSON.stringify(msg));
}
```

The problem I have is with getting [notifications](https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/protocol/tot/page#events). I want to evaluate the code only after navigation has completed (let's say, after the document has loaded). I get messages on the socket in the following way, but as I understand the return message of the `Page.navigate` method is received when the navigation command has been started/received by the debugged page, not when the navigation completes.

```
socket.onmessage = function (event) {
    var data = JSON.parse(event.data);
    switch (data.id) {
        case 1001:
            //A navigation command to app page has been received but not yet navigated
            break;
    }
};
```

How can I use notifications to create a flow such as: Navigate > Wait for navigation to complete > Evaluate some code? I couldn't get any notifications.

Answer (score 1):

The problem was that notifications weren't enabled. To enable notifications:

```
socket.send(JSON.stringify({'id':12345, 'method':'Page.enable'}));
```

Then, notifications are received this way:

```
socket.onmessage = function (event) {
    var data = JSON.parse(event.data);
    switch (data.method) {
        case 'Page.frameNavigated':
            console.log('Navigation completed');
            break;
        //....  
    }
}
```

Same goes for runtime notifications (`Runtime.enable`), network notifications and so on...